# In CakePhp's user authentication will sending username and password with every request slow down app?

Tags: android, api, cakephp, rest

I am trying to create a RESTful API using Cakephp to be consumed by android application.
Will sending the username and password with every api request slowdown the app ? More than 50% of the API calls don't require authentication. And medium-level security is required,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't slow the app down, the username and password will just be sent as headers, or extra POST data. However, it's not very secure if someone's watching the connection, as they can grab the username and password of your client.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, after login is successful, the api should response with a SESSION ID. This SESSION ID should be sent along with every request.

App sending a session id with every api request is fairly a common pattern and wont slow down the app in any way.